# Visual Studio debug failure cannot find AssemblyAttributes.cs

Tags: visual-studio, debugging

After I leave my program running in Debug mode for an extended time, Visual Studio would prompt:

> [Failure] Could not find file
>   'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1.AssemblyAttributes.cs'.
>   [Failure] Could not find file
>   'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.AssemblyAttributes.cs'.

Console messages from the program would not appear in the "Output" tab anymore (this happens to all instances of VS that are currently debugging) and I would have to restart all debugging sessions.

Anyone encountering this problem? How do I fix it?
Thank you.

Comment: I suggest you clean up the temp folder and delete the file, and then rebuild/debug your app. Please also run VS as the admin, view the result.

Comment: Hi, thanks. I will try what you suggested. The problem does not always occur as I am uncertain how long VS needs to be in debug mode to trigger this issue. Thanks.

Comment: Did you remote connect this machine with different user before? I met this issue before which was related to the remote user, I suggest you delete it and rebuild your app, generally it will re-create that file again. Or you could delete .suo file in your solution folder, and then re-open your project files .xxproj, and then clean and build your project, view the result.

Comment: If you get any latest information, feel free to share it. Of course, if you have resolved this issue, you could share your solution as an answer.

Comment: Hi Jack, since my last reply, I ran the Visual Studio installer and updated my VS to the latest version. I have been running my debug sessions for days but so far the issue has not pop up yet. Btw the debug sessions are local. Thank you for replying.

Comment: Glad to know that it has been resolved, if so, would you please share your solution as an answer(not a comment)? You could mark it as the answer, so it could help other community members who get the same issue and we could close this issue for you:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went to https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/ and re-run the setup to update my Visual Studio to the latest version (2017 community). Since then the issue has not crop up again and I assume this has fixed it.

Comment: Really thanks for your sharing, you could mark it as the answer. Have a nice day.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance!